# How to assign simple product with custom options to configurable product & display it along with Configuralbe product

Tags: magento

How to assign simple product with custom options to configurable product and display simple product custom option along with configurable drop downs .(Custom option is a required value)

I have tried "OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProduct" extension which is working as per requirement but it is overriding prices and configurable product add to cart functionality it is adding simple product rather then configurable product with custom options.

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom option in simple product type

go to your admin, click on manage product

find '**Custom Options**' from '**Product Information**' Tab, set you custom option

I think it will help you